# ngDialog in mean.js application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, meanjs

I have created a webapp with MeanJS. I want to use ngDialog in the application, but not sure how and where to add the ngDialog.js in the application. Im trying to inject the ngDialog in the controller as shown below, but everytime error as unknown provider

angular.module('myModule').controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog',
    function ($scope, $http, ngDialog) {

error : 
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider <- ngDialog

Can anyone please let me know how to include the ngDialog in the meanjs application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use bower to install `ngDialog` first. In your application root (where bower.json is located), issue the following command,

`bower install --save ngDialog`

Then, make sure you add ngDialog module in the app level. The following answer is specific to MEAN.JS.

In file `public/config.js`, find the line

`var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils'];`

Add `'ngDialog'` to the end of the list

`var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ngDialog'];`

Then, include ngDialog's CSS and JavaScript file into the HTML template of the Angular application.

In file `config/env/all.js`, find `assets.lib.css`, append `'public/lib/ngDialog/css/ngDialog.min.css'` to the list.

In the same file, find `assets.lib.js`, append `'public/lib/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.min.js'` to the list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have followed your steps still I get error, but this time it is a different error       Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module techkb due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngDialog due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngDialog' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: The problem now is that we have not added the ngDialog js and css file to the html template. See my edited answer to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the ngDialog module in your module, like so: 
`angular.module('myModule', ['ngDialog']).controller('MyController'`...

Answer (score 1):

The original answer is still correct but for the new Mean.js 0.4 some stuff changed.

You still use

```
bower install --save ngDialog
```

to install ngDialog.

To add the dependency `'ngDialog'` go to `modules/core/client/app/config.js` and add

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ngDialog'];
```

Then this is where I struggled.

To include ngDialog's CSS and JavaScript file into the HTML template of the Angular application go to

`config/assets/default.js`

and under `client.lib.css` add `'public/lib/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog.min.css'`

and `client.lib.js` add `'public/lib/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js'` .

Note that the path of ngDialog changed to ng-dialog.